# exception "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException"

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, axios, single-page-application

Using Vue(SPA) in Laravel-8 
I am trying to use event and fetch some data from the component but the data is not being fetched and the error that I am getting is:- **404**

> exception  "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

Here's the **Contacts.vue** that I am using to send **DisplayMessages** event request:-

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Contacts List</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id" >
                           <li>
                           <button @click="displayMesages(contact.id)"> 
                                
                               {{contact.name}} 
                            
                           </button>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                contacts: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/api/contacts-list')
            .then(response => this.contacts = response.data)
        },
        methods: {
            displayMesages(id){
                console.log(id);
                DisplayMessages.$emit('refresh', id);
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Here's the **DisplayMessages.vue** where the request is being receieved:-

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Display Messages</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 v-for="message in messages">{{message.message}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // import contacts from './ContactsList.vue'; 
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                contacts: [],
                messages: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            DisplayMessages.$on('refresh', (id)=>{
                axios.get('/api/display-message/'+ id).then(response => this.messages = response.data)
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's the route **DisplayMessages** is fetching:-

```
Route::get('/api/display-messages/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ChatsController::class, 'displayMessages']);
```

Here's the Controller:-

```
public function displayMessages($id)
    {
        return Chats::all();
        
            }
```

Comment: you are saying you are using `api/display-message/{id}` but you are showing a different route, `api/display-messages/{id}` ... `message != messages`

Comment: In my **web.php** file I have this route ``Route::get('/api/display-messages/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ChatsController::class, 'displayMessages']);`` and I am using the same route in my **DisplayMessages.vue** axios and I'm getting this error, as I am just a beginner I don't know what that error means and why is it showing what's wrong with my codes.

Comment: your javascript code is using `axios.get('/api/display-message/'+ id)` ... that is not `api/display-messages/{id}` ... again, `message != messages`

Comment: Ooo mann thanks... So its just because i'm using message not messages in my axios. I can't check it because my laptop just broke.

Comment: @lagbox You were right it was just a typing mistake can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typing mistake in **DisplayMessages.vue** in axios route:-

```
mounted() {
            DisplayMessages.$on('refresh', (id)=>{
                axios.get('/api/display-message/'+ id).then(response => this.messages = response.data) //It should be '/api/display-messages/`
            });
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this route actually exist and return something?

```
/api/contacts-list
```

Comment: Yes it does return the contacts, The error is coming from ``/api/display-message/{id}``